# Random segmentation fault in D lang on switch break

Tags: linux, d, dmd, ldc

I was debugging a fairly simple program written in D, that seems to have a random chance to receive a SEGV signal. 
Upon further inspection I observed that using different compilers and build modes yielded different results.

Results of my tests:

- DMD Debug = works 99% of the time
- DMD Release = 50/50
- LDC Debug = 50/50
- LDC Release = 50/50

Because the binary from the default compiler (DMD) crashed only once I couldn't really debug it, and release mode didn't help either due to lack of debug symbols.
Building the binary with LDC in debug mode let me test it with gdb and valgrind, to summarize what I gathered.

Relevant information from valgrind,

```
Invalid read of size 4 @ ctor in file video.d line 46

Access not within mapped region at address 0x0 @ ctor in file video.d line
```

Gdb doesn't give me any more insight, 3 stack frames, of which only 0th is of interest, backtrace of frame 0 shows file video.d line 46 which is a break statement, so what now?

This is the snippet of code producing a seg fault

```
module video;

import ffmpeg.libavformat.avformat;
import ffmpeg.libavcodec.avcodec; 
import ffmpeg.libavutil.avutil;

class Foo
{
    private
    {
        AVFormatContext* _format_ctx;
        AVStream* _stream_video;
        AVStream* _stream_audio;
    }

    ...

    public this(const(string) path)
    {
        import std.string : toStringz;

        _format_ctx = null;
        enforce(avformat_open_input(&_format_ctx, path.toStringz, null, null) == 0);
        scope (failure) avformat_close_input(&_format_ctx);

        enforce(avformat_find_stream_info(_format_ctx, null) == 0);
        debug av_dump_format(_format_ctx, 0, path.toStringz, 0);

        foreach (i; 0 .. _format_ctx.nb_streams)
        {
            AVStream* stream = _format_ctx.streams[i];

            if (stream == null)
                continue;

            enforce (stream.codecpar != null);

            switch (stream.codecpar.codec_type)
            {
                case AVMediaType.AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
                    _stream_video = stream;
                    break;
                case AVMediaType.AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO:
                    _stream_audio = stream;
                    break;
                default:
                    stream.discard = AVDiscard.AVDISCARD_ALL;
                    break; // Magic line 46
            }
        }
    }
}

// Might contain spelling errors, had to write it by hand.
```

So does anyone have an idea what causes this behaviour, or more precisely how to go about fixing it?

Comment: have you tried adding some writeln to see if it is actually that line and not like the line before that? The 2 things I would check is if _stream_audio is not null there or if the `scope (failure)` gets called somehow

Comment: My mistake, it was stream.discard, and i added a check before the switch if (stream != null) and the problem still persists

Comment: I think you are experiencing this bug in LDC's debug information: https://github.com/ldc-developers/ldc/issues/2255
Can you check whether there is any nullptr deref on this line: "switch (stream.codecpar.codec_type)"  (codecpar == null?)

Comment: @johan Someone already posted that in dlang forum, and after adding a check there was no change, what I think is more important to address is the fact that DMD in debug doesn't crash, but DMD in release crashes 70% of the time. I used ldc just beacause I couldn't get any info from dmd debug because it didn't crash.

Comment: It is pretty common for code to break in release but not in debug: for example that's what often happens when code is invoking UB.
I think it would help if you can figure out exactly on which line the bug happens. Can you rewrite the switch into a few if-then-else ? (debug lineinfo should be good for that)
Edit: or read the switch condition into a dummy variable and switch on that? Then I think you should also get correct debugline information on the read.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check validity _stream_audio

```
default:
    enforce( _stream_audio, new Exception( "_stream_audio is null" ))
        .discard = AVDiscard.AVDISCARD_ALL;
    break; // Magic line 46
```

Comment: That was a mistake in rewriting, fixed now, also look @comment

Comment: Explain why this will solve the issue and provide a minimum working solution for the user

Answer (score 0):

You are not abiding the warning in the `toStringz` documentation:

“Important Note: When passing a char* to a C function, and the C function keeps it around for any reason, make sure that you keep a reference to it in your D code. Otherwise, it may become invalid during a garbage collection cycle and cause a nasty bug when the C code tries to use it.”

This may not be the cause of your problem, but the way you use `toStringz` is risky.